# Handling HTML Fieldset's size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some this kind of structure

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 48%;">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><b>Company Info:</b> </legend>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                dynamic data
                                <br />
                                 dynamic data
                                <br />
                                dynamic data
                                <br />
                                dynamic data                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 48%;">
                <fieldset id="crew">
                    <legend><b>Crew Company Info:</b> </legend>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                dynamic data
                                <br />
                                dynamic data
                                <br />
                                dynamic data
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Which produces two fieldsets side by side filled with dynamic data, I want to make sure that both fieldsets have same size I mean if one has more data than another one, the another one should increase it's size (height mainly) to overcome that difference so that they both look of same size,

Any suggestion how can I achieve this using CSS or JavaScript ??

Comment: Why? Do you have a border or something else on the `<fieldset>`? If so, why not move that to the `<td>`s that wrap the fieldsets?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can place the fieldset with DIV and use equal size.

Refer [Setting Equal Heights with jQuery](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/)